# Doce logf a string swapper

Tags: code-golf, string, permutations

## Challenge

Take an input string \$s\$, and split it into words \$w_1, w_2, ..., w_n\$. If the amount of words is odd, then return \$s\$. Otherwise, for each word: Take the *second last* letter, and swap it with the first letter keeping capitalization positions. So `GolF` becomes `LogF`.

Now check if the amount of words is a multiple of 2, if they are,
then take the new words and make another set of words \$q_1, q_2, ..., q_{n/2}\$, where \$q_n\$ is a concatenation of \$w_n\$ and \$w_{2n}\$ before applying the whole thing again to the \$q\$ words.

If the amount of words isn't a multiple of 2, then return \$w\$ separated by spaces.

---

## Example

String: `Hello bye hey world woo doo`.

- Split it: `[Hello, bye, hey, world, woo, doo]`
- Is the length an even number? Yes, proceed
- Swap the first and second-last letters: `[Lelho, ybe, ehy, lorwd, owo, odo]`
- Is the length an even number? Yes, make new groups of 2: `[Lelho ybe, ehy lorwd, owo odo]`
- Swap again: `[Belho yle, why lored, dwo ooo]`
- Is the length an even number? No, return `Belho yle why lored dwo ooo`

---

## Notes

- Input words will always have more than 2 characters
- Input will always be letters from a-z, capital or lowercase, and separated by a single space
- Standard loopholes and Default I/O rules apply
- You may not take input in the form of a word list/array
- You don't need to handle edge cases

---

## Test Cases

```
Hello bye hey world woo doo   --> Belho yle why lored dwo ooo
Code golf awesome stuff       --> Goce lodf swesoae ftumf
Very hard code golf challenge --> Very hard code golf challenge (odd length)
Very hard coding stuff        --> Hevy rard sodicg ftunf
```

---

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: will all words contain min 3 letters?

Comment: @Jonah Yes, stated in question

Comment: Shouldn't the last test case return `Nevy rard sodicg ftuhf`?

Comment: How's that? Let me check again..

Comment: Did you mean to type "\$w_{n+1}\$" instead of "\$w_{2n}\$" in "\$q_n\$ is a concatenation of \$w_n\$ and \$w_{2n}\$"?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It shows up as w2n for me...

Comment: @nwellnhof Oh yeah, fixing

Comment: What? Actually, in your example, it looks like \$q_n\$ is \$w_{2n-1}\space w_{2n}\$, not \$w_n\space w_{2n}\$.

Comment: Also "before applying the whole thing again to the q words" is misleading because in step 5 of your example, you don't test whether the number of words is odd before swapping letters.

Comment: @nwellnhof How is it misleading? In step 4 I checked where the number was even ("*Now check if the amount of words is a multiple of 2*") then in step 5 I applied it to the new words

Comment: But in step 4 you also make new groups which leads to the number of words becoming odd. This isn't checked in step 5 which contradicts the challenge description.

Comment: If we have an even number of words at step #2, we still have an even number of words at step #4, don't we?

Comment: @Arnauld But it's just an initial check at the very beginning to make sure we don't have to split an odd-lengthed list

Comment: I believe either the 2nd or the last test case is wrong. They have the same number of words and by applying exactly the same logic, I get `Goce lodf swesoae ftumf` and `Hevy rard sodicg ftunf` respectively.

Comment: @Arnauld Isn't `Hevy rard sodicg ftunf` the last case that I provided? And about the 2nd one, fixing that. I'm generating these test cases by hand since I don't have a program to do it which is the reason for this

Comment: I would add a test cases which has some capitalization in between, instead of only at the beginning of the sentence. I was just about to post a solution when it was closed as unclear.. I think the main reason is because you are talking about _words_, even though in your examples you split the list into two groups (where each group _is two **words**_). It might be better to not use the term words, but instead use strings or something like that: Take a list of strings; if this list is even: swap for each string the first and second-to-last, then merge every 2 with a space delimiter, and continue

Comment: I think the most confusing part is your example, which contradicts your challenge description. You split the input by spaces, and check if it's even: it is, so proceed. Then you swap for each, and split into groups of two. But then you swap again without checking if the list is odd, which it is. I would expect the output `Lelho ybe ehy lorwd owo odo` for input `Hello bye hey World woo doo`. 1. Split by spaces; 2. Check if even: yes, so proceed; 3. Swap for each word; 4. Group per 2 (`["Lelho ybe", "ehy lorwd", "owo odo"]`); 5. Check if even: no, so output joined by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## [Node.js v10.9.0](https://nodejs.org), 171 bytes

```javascript
s=>(h=a=>a.map(w=>Buffer(w).map((c,i,a)=>(i?i-p?c:x:a[x=c,p=w.length-2])&31|c&96)+''),g=n=>n&1?a.join` `:g(n/2,a=h(h(a).join` `.match(/\S+ \S+/g))))((a=s.split` `).length)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBRa8IwEMff9ykOHzTB2qKDwYRUcA/zfbCXbWCWXpJKzJWmWgv77l063WA@eJA8HD9@97/byaMMqi6rZuapwF6LPoicWSFFLtO9rFgr8vVBa6xZy38aTCVlInmkylU5q1ZqeVrKt5NQSSXa1KE3jZ0tPvj4fv6lxo8PfDqZ8MQIL3I/nq9kuqPSb2G7NMxni0QKyyyT/LcdZzTKsuz9ZQrxZYbHYkyKkIbKlU1E@GUK7xX5QA5TR4ZpNtqgcwSfHYLFDlqqXRF/goJoBMA5ZBms0VmCziG0tgNHNRZQtAREdHele4oXAUNOg2wx0B4hNPEUUTXUWfdMCqOl0BAGRiLo5rDX16pXrDuwsi5A/UmVlW5YBEdn1U3mprD05l@0S7YNHjuoByZERpkhmtf9Nw)

#### Commented

The helper function \$h\$ takes an array of words \$a\$ and apply the letter transformation to each of them.

```javascript
h = a =>                     // a[] = input array
  a.map(w =>                 // for each word w in a[]:
    Buffer(w)                //   convert w to a Buffer
    .map((c, i, a) =>        //   for each ASCII code c at position i in this array a[]:
      ( i ?                  //     if this is not the first letter:
          i - p ?            //       if this is not the second last letter:
            c                //         just use c
          :                  //       else:
            x                //         use the backup x of the first letter
        :                    //     else:
          a[                 //       use the second last letter
            x = c,           //       save the first letter in x
            p = w.length - 2 //       p = index of the second last letter
          ]                  //
      ) & 31                 //     use the lower bits of the above character
      | c & 96               //     use the upper bits of the current character (case)
    ) + ''                   //   end of inner map(); coerce the Buffer back to a string
  )                          // end of outer map()
```

Main part:

```javascript
s => (                       // s = input string
  g = n =>                   // g = recursive function taking the number of words n
    n & 1 ?                  // if n is odd:
      a.join` `              //   stop recursion and return a[] joined with spaces
    :                        // else:
      g(                     //   do a recursive call to g:
        n / 2,               //     with n / 2
        a = h(               //     update a[]:
          h(a)               //       apply the letter transformation
          .join` `           //       join with spaces
          .match(/\S+ \S+/g) //       make groups of 2 words
        )                    //     apply the letter transformation again on the result
      )                      //   end of recursive call
)((a = s.split` `).length)   // initial call to g with a[] = list of words, n = length
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 189 bytes

```python
J=' '.join
s=input().split()
f=lambda w,i:(w[~i].lower(),w[~i].upper())[w[i-1].isupper()]
while~len(s)&1:s=[f(w,1)+w[1:-2]+f(w,-1)+w[-1]for w in s];s=[*map(J,zip(s,s[1:]))][::2]
print(J(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxNDoMgFIT3noJVhYomtjsaL@ABuiEsbJX6GgTC0xC78OqW/qwm32S@8es8Onve97bJSV49HdgMG7B@mSmr0BtImenGdNOt70jkIGiUG6jKuDgEyviPFu8/xGSUUNaqAvw3KosjmGEzg6XIDrXARmoaec2KKGtRnlTxwfLLydQukEjAElSXND1Onactf4GnyDEJijElhTipzAewM23TK9v36xBWMnahJ3fXg30QnBet3w)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 68 bytes

```
≔⪪Ｓ θＦ¬﹪Ｌθ²«≔¹ηＷ¬﹪Ｌθη«≔ＥＥ⪪θη⪫λ ⭆⭆Ｅλ⁻⁻Ｌλξ²§λ⎇∧νξξν⎇№α§λξ↥ν↧νθ≔²η»»⪫θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBasMwDIbPzVOInmTIDuu1p7DLOpox6PYAXuLVBiMljrMkjD57ZsdpYIcdJCz0/fIvVVq6iqWd56LrzJXw0ljj8URN7y/eGbqiyGEP@5Bbccy@2AG@sseS694ynhVdvcY2tA9CCPjJduugxxx0EOwGbaz6T6NXzV1UymaJ5KKNQA4vbAhtchHKZGuhtleMQJSG@g5TXn@xQTEmdzkU/kS1GiP6rhxJN2FBNVJCxhxIROzee@KePMo/ujECH02jXCU7hRSqMw9btejjobaVDusdbtktewt@PS77tOs@x3l@VtYyfE4KtJpgYGfrkBlq5mx@@La/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪪Ｓ θ
```

Split the input on spaces.

```
Ｆ¬﹪Ｌθ²«
```

Do nothing if the number of words is odd.

```
≔¹η
```

Don't pair the words up on the first pass.

```
Ｗ¬﹪Ｌθη«
```

Repeat while the number of words is even.

```
≔ＥＥ⪪θη⪫λ ...θ
```

Pair the words up, map over the paired words, and save the result.

```
Ｅλ⁻⁻Ｌλξ²
```

Map each character index to the length of the word minus the index minus 2.

```
⭆...§λ⎇∧νξξν
```

Map each character to itself unless its index or the above calulation is zero in which case use the character at the index given by the above calculation.

```
⭆...⎇№α§λξ↥ν↧ν
```

Map each character to upper or lower case depending on whether the original character of that word was upper or lower case.

```
≔²η»»
```

Pair the words up on successive passes.

```
⪫θ
```

Join the (remaining) words on spaces and implicitly print.